Need help with identifying the resistor or probably the problem with the ultrasonic cleaner
My father was trying to use an ultrasonic cleaner and the fuse blew. I changed the fuse, tried it again and it blew again. Probably something off with the circuit. Then i noticed a resistor is kinda blown. Now, I can't determine the value of it. I only found one picture of the circuit on the internet.

The resistor that blew is R1 (the closest to the fuse, next to the big red cap)
I know there are sites on the web that could help.. Trust me I tried...


You need an image citation.

Is the picture in the question from the board which has failed, or one of a working circuit found on the internet?

sorry, i fixed the image now

@ChesterGillon the image is the working circuit found on the internet, i will attach my blown resistor too

That is a tricky 5-band resistor to decode. Is it purple-yellow-black-orange-brown? It makes little sense regardless of which way to decode it. It may make sense to not see what it is but what it does in the circuit. If it is the discharge resistor for C1 then you know you can replace it with something similar, not identical. As an idenrify resistor question this is OK, but it is close to being a repair question without understanding the circuit.

please add a link to the source of the picture ... also, add a picture of the other side of the board

the post is on a russian site link there's also more images there

The resistor is probably just a symptom, not root cause. Check all semiconductors for shorts.

okay thanks, i will look into it
